# Transform stream JavaScript for the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-side, through2

I have a file that makes use of the library `through2` to handle transform streams. The only problem with this library is that it doesn't run on the browser. Is there a library I can use that does something similar to `through2` and runs on the client?  Otherwise, what's the best way to tackle this problem? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can't read files from browser javascript vm, that would be a big security issue

Comment: I'm just trying to send data back and forth in chunks to another package project. I'm not sure I am attempting to read files.